# Date format conversion Android

Tags: java, android, date

I have string form of date:

```
2011-03-27T09:39:01.607
```

and I want to format it to `March 27, 2011`

I am using

```
DateFormat[] formats = new DateFormat[] {
DateFormat.getDateInstance(), DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(),
         DateFormat.getTimeInstance(), };
String actDate= formats[0].format(uploadeddate.substring(0,9));
```

but its not working.

How do I convert to `March 27, 2011`?

Comment: try [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I have created a method for such problem. refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042733/4531507

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = null;
try 
{
    date = form.parse("2011-03-27T09:39:01.607");
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
```

now `newDateStr = March 27, 2011;`

Answer (score 9):

May be this is of any help;

```
String convertDate(String inputDate) {

    DateFormat theDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = theDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
    } catch (ParseException parseException) {
        // Date is invalid. Do what you want.
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        // Generic catch. Do what you want.
    }

    theDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

    return theDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: The format of date in first line, does not match with the format of input string. Anyways, this answer will also provide some help to the new comer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `android.text.format.DateFormat` in this way:

```
DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(context).format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String dateimput = "2011-03-27T09:39:01.607"

SimpleDateFormat formatrecived = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");    
SimpleDateFormat formarwanted = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

Date recived = formatrecived.parse(dateimput);

Date output = formatwanted.format(recived);
```

**Note: dateimput you need to format to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` using replace and substring**

Answer (score 1):

To get AM or PM and 12 hour date format use `hh:mm:ss a` as string formatter where `hh` is for 12 hour format and `a` is for AM PM format.

### note ## HH is for 24 hour and `hh` is for 12 hour date format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```

### example

```
String date = "2011/11/12 16:05:06";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
    Date testDate = null;
    try {
        testDate = sdf.parse(date);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
    System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create a format for your date to be able to parse the date out into the way you want it.

The formatted well have to be exactly the format of your timestamp and then what I did is create another format as to what I want the date to look like and then parse the it.

Check out the documentation for exactly what to use to format and then what to use to parse. Once I figured this out it got a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2011-03-27T09:39:01.607", DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "M-" );
String output = formatter.withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH ).print( dateTime );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String strDate, String sourceFormate,
        String destinyFormate) {
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormate);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(strDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    df = new SimpleDateFormat(destinyFormate);
    return df.format(date);

}
```

Call it like:

```
getFormatedDate(strDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I should like to contribute the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);

    String uploadeddate = "2011-03-27T09:39:01.607";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(uploadeddate);
    String actDate = ldt.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(actDate);
```

When I set my default locale to English and run this snippet, the output is what you asked for:

> March 27, 2011

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in the standard ISO 8601 format, and that the classes of java.time parse this format as their default. Usually when reformatting a date/time string from one format to another, two formatters are used, one that specifies the format to convert *from* and one for the format to convert *to*. But since your source format is the default, we can make do with only one formatter here.

### What went wrong in your code?

- Your counting is wrong: `uploadeddate.substring(0,9)` gives you `2011-03-2` where I’m sure you intended `2011-03-27`.
- You passed a `String` to `formats[0].format()`, but it cannot format a string. It accepts either a `Date` or a `Long`, so you would have needed to convert to one of these first. The code compiles, but throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)