# Android Date format conversion 71

Tags: android

I have a date in 02/21/2013 04:52:10 PM this format.

How do I convert it into MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm. I already tried few things but it keeps throwing error

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02/21/2013 04:52:10 PM" (at offset 2)

I really need a help from date format expert.
Thanks

Comment: How are you storing this date ? what variable? type of variable ? where are you storing it?

Comment: I am storing 02/21/2013 04:52:10 PM in sqlite in String format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

try {
    System.out.println("Converted: " + outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse("02/21/2013 04:52:10 PM")));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output: **01-21-2013 16:52**

Checkout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Construct two SimpleDateFormat objects. The first you parse() the value from into a Date object, the second you use to turn the Date object back into a string, e.g.

```
try {
  DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  return df2.format(df1.parse(input));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
  return null;
}
```

Parsing can throw a ParseException so you would need to catch and handle that.

In addition, check this out:-

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

and more:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx

and more:-

[Date format conversion Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896635/date-format-conversion-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Does "/" or "-" matter ?  Does yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' is same as yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'

Comment: code it, debug it, learn it. best way to learn coding, my friend.

Comment: :) doing all of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need verify if your String have / or - in the mask, case have / then you must used:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", LOCALE_BR);
Date convert = sdf.parse(data);
```

case your String have - then you must used:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", LOCALE_BR);
    Date convert = sdf.parse(data);
```

Or then, use the `replace()` for change of the caracter - for /