# In Java, extract time only from datetime format-yyyyMMdd HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, android

I have date column in my database which store date in `yyyyMMdd HH:MM:SS` format. Please let me know how to retrieve the time part that is HH:MM:SS in android so that it does not hit performance.

Comment: This: yyyyMMdd HH:MM:SS should be: **yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss**

Comment: After Retreiving Records From Data Base Convert the Date to format of your Choice http://stackoverflow.com/a/6896822/1696704

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date format conversion Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896635/date-format-conversion-android)