# How to convert DateTime received from Wordpress to a more readable format?

Tags: android, datetime

> Hello, I am receiving dateTime in this format :

```
2016-01-21T11:03:56
```

> I want to convert this into a more readable format like :

```
January-02-2021 or similar
```

> I tried these guides but unable to do so
> https://androidwave.com/format-datetime-in-android/ and
> https://www.javatpoint.com/java-date-to-string

> Also, tried this code, but no luck :

```
 Date date = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
String strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with MM/dd/yyyy : "+strDate);
```

> Pls Guide

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I’m immodest enough to recommend [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677650/5772882) for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the date based on the formats, the snnipt below includes 2 type of result.

```
try {
        //normal format of date
        SimpleDateFormat resultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-dd-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String input = "2016-01-21T11:03:56";
        Date resultDate = inputFormat.parse(input);
        String normalDateResult = resultFormat.format(resultDate);
        String monthDateResult = monthFormat.format(resultDate);
        System.out.println(normalDateResult); // 21-01-2016
        System.out.println(monthDateResult); //January-21-2016

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```